# VBA macro error, how do I fix this error?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I want to sort
Column A3 until end:

1. Change all column A3 until end value into "ID"

Column B3 until end:

1. Sort A to Z
2. Text to column: column date format to text

This is the code I made by recording my macro but it does not work in every data. Please help me fix this. Thankyou

```
Sub Sort2()
'
' Sort2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ID"
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A3:A30").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-135
    Range("B3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tickets Received").ListObjects("Tickets").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tickets Received").ListObjects("Tickets").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B3:B126"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tickets Received").ListObjects("Tickets").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B3"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("C7").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add an image of your table please?  I take it everything is happening inside the `Tickets` table.

Comment: *it does not work in every data* Welcome to SO. What do you mean? What error are you getting? Which line?

Answer (score 0):

This will place the word **ID** on every row in the column headed *ID* and will sort by the T*ickets Received* column.
Not sure how to split the *Tickets Received* column - what data is in there?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tickets Received").ListObjects("Tickets")
    
    With lo
        .ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange = "ID" 'DataBodyRange is the whole column (in the table) minus the header.
        
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.ListColumns("Tickets Received").DataBodyRange, _
                              SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                              Order:=xlAscending, _
                              DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.Apply
    End With
    
End Sub
```

NB:  [ThisWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook) represents the workbook where the current macro code is running.
[ActiveWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook) represents the workbook in the active window (the window on top).
It's easy to reference the wrong workbook using `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the help. The column B is ticket numbers and what I want to do is to change the number format to text with text to column (change column data format from general to text) - not splitting. Sorry for the confusion, English is not my first language